# How to make an edge similar to this image

Tags: modeling

[image: Semi circle.ish edges]

Hello, I would like to have this kind of edge on my plane instead of a straight surface. how can I achieve this...

I had tried adding circles but the straight surface edge shows.If I bring the series of circles slightly towards the front the circle outlines will be the ones showing instead. New to blender, kindly help

Answer (score 2):

Create a 12 vertex circle, remove the bottom, activate the *Auto Merge* and the *Snap To* vertex options, duplicate it on X, merge the second with the first one, extrude down, scale on Z (<kbd>S</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>):

[image]

Comment: Thank you. How did you flat out the semi curve at the end

Comment: press S+Z+0 (to flatten on Z)